# Function Sequence on Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Another analysis question:

$f_n\to F$ uniformly on $D$; $f_n$ is continuous on $D$. $x_n$ is a sequence with $x_n\to x$.

Prove that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_n)=F(x)$$

I've done some basic fudging, but really have no idea where to go from here once again.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I can google LaTeX and learn the formatting from there?

Comment: @Paul: Please see the following link for how to write posts in MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hm. Me and this other guy edited the question (adding LaTeX) at the same time, without realizing. Now, looking at the edit log, apparently both of our edits were accepted, one after the other, even though they did the same thing. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f_n \to F$ uniformly on $D$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $|f_n(t) - F(t)| < \varepsilon/2$ for all $t\in D$. Since $F$ is continuous (being the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions), there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $t\in D$, $|t - x| < \delta$ implies $|F(t) - F(x)| < \varepsilon/2$. As $x_n \to x$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $|x_n - x| < \delta$ for all $n \ge k$. Let $j = \max\{k,N\}$. If $n \ge j$, then $|x_n - x| < \delta$, which implies $|F(x_n) - F(x)| < \varepsilon$, and consequently

$$|f_n(x_n) - F(x)| \le |f_n(x_n) - F(x_n)| + |F(x_n) - F(x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n) = F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume that $f_n\xrightarrow{\text{uniformly}} F$ on $D$ and $f_n$'s are continuous. Then $F$ is continuous on $D$. Assume that $x_n\to x$ on $D$. Hence prove the following steps to obtain $f_n(x_n)\to F(x)$.

1. First show that $f_n\to F$ uniformly on $D\Longleftrightarrow M_n:=\sup\limits_{t\in D}|f_n(t)-F(t)|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$
2. Show that for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $|f_n(x_n)-F(x_n)|\le M_n\to 0$   (use step-1).
3. Use the continuity of $F$ to show that $|F(x_n)-F(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.
4. Hence conclude that $|f_n(x_n)-F(x)|\le |f_n(x_n)-F(x_n)|+|F(x_n)-F(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly and $f$ is the limit of continuous functions, so $f$ is continuous.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then $\exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N_1\implies |f(x_n)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Because we have that each $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, there is $N_2\in\mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N_2\implies |f_n(y)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $\forall y\in D$.

Then let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$. Then for $\forall n\geq N$ we have that

$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$